# How draw lines between and fill on 4 points on an ASP.NET page?

Tags: html, gps, system.drawing

Using GPS, I will know the latitude/longitude for 4 corners of a lot of land (I suppose it could be 5 or 6 so a polygon -- although will usually be a rectangle or parallelogram).  Using DIV tags (with runat=server), I can mark the dots on an ASP.NET page pulling the data points from a database.

But, is there a way I can essentially turn these into shapes?  I'm trying to map out a, for example, subdivision of plats on a web page.  Ultimately, I'd like data to appear on mouseover, have unsold plats a different color, click on a plat and it navigates somewhere, etc).

But right now, I'm just trying to see if I can plot the shapes on a page.

Thanks very much for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

If you can count on your users having a modern browser, html5 `<canvas>` is probably what you want.  You can just put a canvas on your page with
`<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>`

Then draw to it in javascript like so:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");  
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");  
ctx.fillStyle = '#f00';    
ctx.beginPath();    
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);  
ctx.lineTo(0, 100);  
ctx.lineTo(50, 100);  
ctx.lineTo(50, 0);  
ctx.closePath();  
ctx.fill();
```

Adjust or add corners as needed.